# Update array item order without moving it

Tags: javascript

I have following array of objects.

```
[
  { id: 1, title: 't1', order: 0 },
  { id: 2, title: 't1', order: 1 },
  { id: 3, title: 't1', order: 2 },
]
```

I want to reorder items several times.
In the first try.

```
// move id: 1, fromOrder: 0, toOrder: 2
[
  { id: 1, title: 't1', order: 2 },
  { id: 2, title: 't2', order: 0 },
  { id: 3, title: 't3', order: 1 },
]
```

In the second try.

```
// move id: 3, fromOrder: 1, toOrder: 0
[
  { id: 1, title: 't1', order: 2 },
  { id: 2, title: 't2', order: 1 },
  { id: 3, title: 't3', order: 0 },
]
```

As you can see the point is that I am not going to move the item, I just want to update the order attribute.

I did something like below but it does not work as expected.

```
const reorder = (array, id, oldIndex, newIndex) => {
  const ordered = array
    .map(item => item.order === newIndex ? { ...item, order: oldIndex } : item)
    .map(item => item.id === id ? { ...item, order: newIndex } : item);
  
  return ordered;
};
```

***Post Answer Third Party Clarification Edit***
*The user wanted to shift all item's orders around (including wrapping around), rather than just swapping two values, preserving the relative orders.*

Comment: What is the rule on the new order?

Comment: well what does the part of the code that calls 'reorder' look like? the example is incomplete

Comment: @epascarello I just want to update the `order` based on recent update array. There is no specific rule.

Comment: "based on recent update array" still no clue what that means.

Comment: I tried this code using just the code you provided, and it worked: `arr = reorder(arr, 1, 2, 2);
arr = reorder(arr, 2, 0, 1);
arr = reorder(arr, 3, 1, 0);`

Comment: "I want to reorder items several times.
In the first try." what you post afterward doesn't match what you say you're trying to do. you say `move id: 1, fromOrder: 0, toOrder: 2` but then the json you post doesn't match either what does actually happen, nor does it match what should happen.

Comment: When you use `reorder`, are you trying to **swap** the elements at positions `oldIndex` and `newIndex`, or shift all of the items around (looping back to the start if need be)? In either case you don't need `oldIndex` I wouldn't think.

Comment: @dantechguy Exactly, I am going to shift all items based on the new order

Comment: the easy thing to do is first sort them, then step through the records setting your "order" value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Most true to your code option

All you have to do is calculate the difference between the start and end index, and shift all item's order by that value.

```js
const reorder = (array, id, oldIndex, newIndex) => {
  orderShift = newIndex-oldIndex;
  const ordered = array.map(item => {
    item.order = mod(item.order + orderShift, array.length);
    return item;
  });
  return ordered;
};
```

### Most efficient option

The below code is an optimised function, since you don't need to specify the item's id or any specific indexes, only how much to shift by.

```js
const reorder = (array, shift) => {
  for (let i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++) {
    array[i].order = mod(array[i].order + shift, len);
  }
  return array;
};
```

### Most useful option

If you don't know its current location, and want to specify the `newIndex`, then you can alternatively use the function below.

```js
const reorder = (array, id, newIndex) => {
  let shift = newIndex - array.find(x => x.id === id).order;
  for (let i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++) {
    array[i].order = mod(array[i].order + shift, len);
  }
  return array;
};
```

### Extra needed function

Since JavaScript doesn't have a modulo operator (only the `%` "remainder" operator), I use this function as a quick shortcut.

```js
// you'll need this mod function in all of the above options
function mod(n, m) {
  return ((n % m) + m) % m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a for loop and increment the array, when you get to the max or end of array jump it back to zero.

```js
var data = [
  { id: 1, title: 't1', order: 0 },
  { id: 2, title: 't2', order: 1 },
  { id: 3, title: 't3', order: 2 },
  { id: 4, title: 't4', order: 3 },
  { id: 5, title: 't5', order: 4 },
  { id: 6, title: 't6', order: 5 },
  { id: 7, title: 't7', order: 6 },
  { id: 8, title: 't8', order: 7 },
];

const debugIt = array => console.log(array.map(x => `${x.id} - ${x.order}`)); 

const reorder = (array, id, newIndex) => {

  let index = array.findIndex(x => x.id === id);
  var max = array.length - 1;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    array[index].order = newIndex;
    index++
    newIndex++;
    if (index > max) index = 0;
    if (newIndex > max) newIndex = 0;
  }

};

debugIt(data);
reorder(data, 4, 0);
debugIt(data);
reorder(data, 7, 0);
debugIt(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in a deleted post, you don't need to ask `oldIndex`.

As I understand your code, you switch places the arrays items instead of shifting them around. What you have to do is decrement or increment the index of all the elements between the old and the new index :

```js
const reorder = (array, id, newIndex) => {
  const oldIndex = array.findIndex(item => item.id == id);
  const ordered = array
    .map(item =>
      (item.order > oldIndex && item.order <= newIndex) ? // implicit check of oldIndex < newIndex
         { id: 1, title: 't1', order: item.order-1 } :
      (item.order < oldIndex && item.order >= newIndex) ? // implicit check of oldIndex > newIndex
         { id: 1, title: 't1', order: item.order+1 } :
      (item.id == id) ?
         { id: 1, title: 't1', order: newIndex } :
         item
    );
  
  return ordered;
};
```